# Is there a way to have a checkbox toggle the text color of a set range?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, checkbox, colors, fonts

I have a Google Sheets document and there is a dynamic list that gets created in a certain range (J19:L26) that has some personal data in it. Is there a way to make a checkbox or something quick I can click (even a button?) that can set the text to white or background to black to hide it to onlookers? I currently have the checkbox in cell M17

I have the following code that executes fine but then when I check the box in M17 nothing happens. Maybe I missed a step somewhere? I am new to Google sheets coding. I just wrote the function, tested it Runs, then closed it. Maybe I am just missing a step(s) in implementing the function to my sheet or my function Runs but doesn't do what I need it to?

```
function Privacy() {
  var TheBoard = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var TheRange = TheBoard.getRange("Board!J19:L26");
  if(TheBoard.getRange("Board!M17") == "TRUE")
  {
    TheBoard.getRange(TheRange).setFontColor('white');    
  } 
}
```

Comment: Hope my answer helped you. If it solved your issue please consider marking it as accepted so others can also benefit from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things to correct. Here's a list:

- When getting the status of the checkbox you're using `TheBoard.getRange("Board!M17")`. The [`getRange()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation) method returns a reference to the range, not the value. After getting the range you can use [`getValue()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue) on it to retrieve the values, so it should be `TheBoard.getRange("Board!M17").getValue()`, which will return `true` or `false` depending on the status of the checkbox.
- You're comparing the value of the checkbox to `== "TRUE"`. That makes it a string, and the checkbox value returns a boolean. In Javascript you're supposed to declare booleans as `true` or `false`, lowercase without quotes. That means the comparison should be `== true` instead.
- The line `TheBoard.getRange(TheRange).setFontColor('white');` returns an error. This is because `getRange()` expects a range in A1 notation or the coordinates to the row and column, but you're plugging `TheRange` into it, which is already a `Range` object. You already defined `TheRange`, so you don't need to "get" it again. The line should be just `TheRange.setFontColor('white');`
- If you want to make the script run automatically when you click the checkbox you need to set it up as an `onEdit()` [trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers). Then within the trigger check if the field that was edited was the checkbox before proceeding.
- It's probably better to create a separate variable for the Sheet to avoid having to specify it in every range call.
- May be a nitpick, but capitalizing variables makes the formatting color them like Classes, which may become confusing so I advise not doing that.

That said, here's the script with all the corrections:

```js
function onEdit(e) {

  if (e.range.getA1Notation() == "M17") {
    var theBoard = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var theSheet = theBoard.getSheetByName("Board")
    var theRange = theSheet.getRange("J19:L26");

    if (theBoard.getRange("M17").getValue() == true) {
      theRange.setFontColor('white');
    } else {
      theRange.setFontColor('black');
    }
  }
}
```

I recommend you familiarize yourself with the official documentation to better understand how each method works and apply them correctly.

##### Sources:

- [Sheet Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)
- [Range Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)
- [Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)